# Why do I have to login twice?

Tags: virtuemart, login, joomla-1.5

I have a Joomla 1.5 website that has a problem - when you login, it doesn't log you in and says "Your session has expired. Please log in again." as a blue error message. However the page it is on is titled "Registered Area" and then says "Welcome to the registered user area of our site.".

I go through the cart and the details are not logged in so you have to login again, and it works.

Why is this? I haven't done anything to the site recently.

Comment: There are quite a few posts regarding this issue. Please do a Google search ;)

Comment: Could you link me? Am extremely busy this week.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=joomla+virtuemart+login+twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an .htaccess file to overwrite the URL so "www." is always at the beginning of the URL. Otherwise it went wrong.

Code for the file:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]